# How much positive contribution is required to outweigh poorly received questions?

Tags: support, reputation, post-ban

Although I tried hard to write better questions, most of my maths questions have been poorly received :(

Two questions were down-voted, so before they annoyed anybody else, I deleted them myself like the system suggested and found that this instantly resulted in me losing my question rights.

I've worked hard to make a positive contribution and gained a few hundred reputation, but is there any indication how much I need to do before I can again use the "ask questions" feature?  Does it depend on my activity on other Stack Exchange sites too?

P.S. There's no need to tell me perhaps it would be better all round if I didn't ask any more questions!

Comment: Have you tried to undelete your questions and improve them (or change them if there is no answer already)?

Comment: @Surb I don't think I can find them any more.  I just tried improving another downvoted question so we'll see how that goes.  I tried improving another question based on feedback and commenters got annoyed because their comments no longer made sense in respect of the re-worded question.

Comment: You might flag a moderator if a comment is completely out of scope. (but they have a lot to do, so be reasonable)